# How to convert (fmap?) function X => Boolean to Rep[X] => Rep[Boolean] in Slick?

Tags: scala, slick

Let's assume I have a function from `X => Boolean` where `X` is some class that can be compared. I also have a DAO that reads a collection of `X` from the database. I would like the function in DAO to look like this:

`retrieveXs(criteria: X => Boolean)`

And then use the `criteria` function inside Slick's `filter` function like this:

`XQuery.filter(criteria).result`

So for example I could do something like this:

`retrieveXs(((a :X) => (b: X) => b > a)(X(1)))`

So I would get all the elements from the database that are greater than `X(1)`.

Of course Slick's filter function expects `Rep[X] => Rep[Boolean]` so my question is how do I lift my `criteria` function to `Rep[X] => Rep[Boolean]` assuming I've already have a mapping for `X`. This sounds like a job for something like `fmap`, but I can't find how to do it.